# Is there a way to change the colour of displaced areas only?

Tags: rendering, color, displacement, procedural, vertex-colors

I've created this model and created displacement using a combination of weight painting and the displacement modifier to create some intense wrinkles. Is there way that i can change the colour or material of the displaced areas/wrinkles without altering the rest of the mesh?

Is this something that could be achieved through procedurally generated displacement instead of the modifier.

Any help welcome :) [image]

Answer (score 3):

Using nodes might be a bit faster.
Simply use the same Displacement texture as a mask for *MixRGB node* and select the colors.

You can also use *MixShader node* to mix different shaders.

[image]